# Which derived categories of coherent sheaves are equivalent (or "$t$-related") to derived categories of rings?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, kt.k-theory-and-homology, derived-categories, coherent-sheaves, t-structure

As far as I understand, it was Beilinson who proved that the bounded derived category of coherent sheaves $D^b(\mathbb{P}^n)$ is equivalent to the bounded derived category of a certain (non-commutative) ring. My question is: for which (not necessarily projective) varieties or schemes isomorphisms of the form $D^b(X)\cong D^b(R_X)$ are known to exist?

More generally, when there exists a $t$-structure on $D^b(X)$ or on $D(X)$ whose heart is a certain category of $R$-modules? It appears that this question is related to tilting complexes of sheaves, but this does not help me much. What are the standard references for these matters?

Comment: It may well be that this is only possible when the varieties are cohomologically simple, projective spaces, grassmannians, quadrics. I doubt there is such description in "general type" varieties, but this is just a guess.

Comment: If you're willing to go to dg-algebras, I think smooth and proper is enough by Bondal and Van Den Bergh https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0204218

Comment: I am not willing to go to dg algebras since this will not yield a t-structure.:) And I have a trivial family of examples: one can certainly take $X$ to be an affine variety.

Comment: Well, for what it's worth, I believe all the del Pezzos have tilting objects and I believe Craw has proved it true for a class of toric varieties. I know more has been done, but I'd just end up googling "tilting object" and "tilting sheaf" to get a more up-to-date answer.

Comment: If such $R_X$ exists then Hochschild homology of $X$ is concentrated in non-negative homological degrees. In characteristic zero HKR theorem (for smooth $X$) $HH_i(X)=\bigoplus\limits_{p-q=i}H^q(X,\Omega^p)$ then implies that $H^q(X,\Omega^p)=0$ for $q>p$. If $X$ is smooth proper this implies that $H^{p,q}(X)=0$ when $p\neq q$, so the cohomology of such smooth proper variety would have to be Tate.